# Device reboots on recording video

Tags: android, exoplayer, video-recording

I have used [Exoplayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) for recording videos. This is working fine for almost all the devices, but for a few of them (Samsung Galaxy S9+ being one of them) is experiencing reboot issue while the video is recorded. The device automatically restarts on its own. Since this is not an app-crash, this cannot be even recorded on Crashlytics.
Had anyone faced the same issue - Any solution for this or any way to debug the exact issue using logs or any other medium?? Thanks.

Comment: Some Samsung S9 users face randomly shut down problem https://us.community.samsung.com/t5/Galaxy-S9-Questions-and-Answers/S9-randomly-shuts-off/td-p/333794. @Bhavna It might be possible that your issue is due to the above shutdown problem. Please check the link for the solution.